# TFS 2010 -> TFS 2015 cloned environment PrepareClone throws error

Tags: tfs, clone, upgrade, tfs-2015

I'm preparing for an upgrade from `TFS 2010 SP1` to `TFS 2015`. We've created new test servers and copied the db's to the new servers. I'm trying to run the `PrepareClone` command and get this error:

> "Exception:Could not find stored procedure 'prc_GetServiceVersion'.
>   Command:EXEC prc_GetServiceVersion @serviceName=DatabaseManagement"

I'm not sure what do to do next, can I skip this step and run the `ChangeServerIDs`?  I'm concerned there is something missing from the database and will run into issues later.

Comment: Are you running PrepareClone with the TFS 2015 tools?

Comment: Yes, 2015 update 1

Comment: I would expect that you would need perform the preparation steps for the clone using the TFS 2010 tooling.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... Prepare Clone and ChangeServerID are run with the latest tools once the database is hooked up to the new server.

Comment: But you haven't upgraded it yet right? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Right, as I understand it, you are supposed to run the PrepareClone and ChangeServerID commands before you run the upgrade wizard.  Thats what the documentation says.. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx.  It seems that no one else has run into this issue!

Comment: Yes, because you have to move your server using the steps relevant to the version of TFS you are currently on not the one you are upgrading to.

Comment: But TFS 2010 isn't supported on windows server 2012... so how is that possible?

Comment: What do you see in version information of Data Tier Summary in TFS Admin Console?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `PrepareClone` command **should be run before configuration**, whether you move or clone TFS.

If you run it after configuration, you could end up with inconsistencies between content in your databases and content in your web.config file. Since the server of TFS2010 have been updated to TFS2015 during the  Tfs_Configuration, there are different versions. However, the command are still pointing to the old TFS connection strings
.

If you have already configured your moved or cloned TFS deployment and realize you need to run the command, follow below steps:

1. First, quiesce your server.
2. Next, run `PrepareClone` command, `ChangeServerID` command, and then
   `RemapDBs` command.
3. Finally, unquiesce your server.

If it still not work, you may need to restore the backups to the appropriate server, uninstall TFS 2015, install TFS 2010 on the same machine, and run the commands for PrepareClone, ChangeServerID, and RemapDBs.